# If a JUnit test fails with timeout will it run a finally clause?

Tags: java, junit

Supose we have a junit test with timeout like this:

```
@Test(timeout=10)
public void testWithTimeout(){
    try{
        doSomethingLongerThan10();
    } finally {
        cleanup();
    }
}
```

If the test takes longer and ends with a timeout will it run the finally clause?
Will it just end?
Will it leave a thread running?

I have observed in my own tests that the finally clause is not run but I don't know if it is this way on every possible jUnit test or it depends on the version or the runner class.

Comment: This is easy to test

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: thanks to Sotirios Delimanolis for pointing out the "bad test"

---

Because I was curious I did test it:

```
public class Foo {
    @Test(timeout=10)
    public void testWithTimeout() {
        try {
            while(true)
                ;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("did run");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
org.junit.runners.model.TestTimedOutException: test timed out after 10 milliseconds
at so32723397.Foo.testWithTimeout(Foo.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**So the answer is no.** (junit 4.12)

Comment: I was lazier then you, I did exactly the same (for the same reasons) with Thread.sleep(100).

Comment: :) (as a side note, I would have bet on finally is not run..)

Comment: Which incites me to test it with a `org.junit.rules.Timeout` for completeness sake, brb.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `Timeout` rule, good to know (same behavior here)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis good catch, with a forever loop its not run

Comment: Yep same also, was expecting a maybe different behaviour since it run on the same thread.